# Filter by datetime MYSQL formatting

Tags: mysql, date, datetime-format

I have a Mysql Table that is used for a log file on the that table there is a field called 'log_date' And it stores the date in the following format( %Y-%m-%d %H:%i.%s ).On the DB the dates look like something this 2013-20-05 00:00.00. Lets say today's date is 2013-20-05 And I have log files from 2013-01-01 to present day. If I run a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM log_table
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(log_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i.%s') < '2013-05-05 00:00.00'
```

This is returning every row in the DB including rows that are greater than 2013-05-05 00:00.00

And if I reverse the < (less then) to a > (greater then) with a query that looks like this:

```
SELECT * FROM log_table
WHERE STR_TO_DATE(log_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i.%s') > '2013-05-05 00:00.00'
```

Then it returns ZERO rows. I think the time stamp is what is causing the problem I have worked with the date format before but not the DateTime format. Why is this happening?

Comment: What is the data type for `log_date`?

Answer (score 47):

log_date should be of DateTime data type. It is much simpler to use MySQL DATE function. Some examples

```
SELECT * FROM log_table
WHERE DATE(log_date) < '2013-05-05'

SELECT * FROM log_table
WHERE DATE(log_date) > '2013-05-05'

SELECT * FROM log_table
WHERE DATE(log_date) BETWEEN '2013-04-05' AND '2013-05-05'

SELECT * FROM log_table
WHERE DATE(log_date) BETWEEN DATE(CURRENT_DATE() - INTERVAL 2 WEEK) AND 
DATE(CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL 4 DAY)
```

Comment: It may be simpler but it's not efficient. I'll +1 you if you tell me why.

Comment: okay, ill shoot :).  impossible to use indexes with built-in functions in the WHERE clause

Comment: Thank you blotto I have tried using just the DATE function but still no effect. I think it has something to do with the format of the date itself  "2013-05-05 00:00.00" with it including the %H:%i.%s'. the strange part is the less then sign will return all rows regardless of the date and the greater then always returns zero rows. In the past when I only use the YYYY-DD-MM it sorts perfectly but this format includes time.

Comment: Thank you everybody the problem was one of syntax I was inserting a period in the last part of my date 2out the b013-20-05 00:00 . 0 (without the blank space) when on the DB the format used : on the last digit. the final code looked like this:

    SELECT * FROM 
    WHERE DATE_FORMAT(log_date , '%Y-%d-%m %H:%i:%s') > '2013-18-05 00:00:00'

Answer (score 1):

You can try with that..

```
WHERE DATE_FORMAT(AUCTION_DATE, '%Y%m%d') >= DATE_FORMAT('2013/5/18', '%Y%m%d')
```

You can also get today date using **now()** function.

Comment: You shouldn't do that: the `DATE_FORMAT()` is computed for every row, instead of testing against a constant, which `DATE_FORMAT('2013/5/18', '%Y%m%d')` is. So you'd better: `WHERE AUCTION_DATE >= DATE_FORMAT('2013/5/18', '%Y%m%d')`, which can use indexes.