# DynamicReports not producing report with where clause on date

Tags: java, mysql, jasper-reports, dynamic-reports

I'm facing a very strange issue. I'm trying to generate report in [DynamicReports API](http://www.dynamicreports.org/). The report is being generated without *WHERE* clause but is not being generated with *WHERE* clause. The database is MySQL. Any help is much appreciated. Here is the code:

**Service class:**

```
public class ReportSevice {
    public void createReport (String reportDate) {
        System.out.println(reportDate); 
        String sql_statement = null;
        Connection connection = null;
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            connection = DriverManager.getConnection(
                    "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/world","root", "password");
            sql_statement = "SELECT id, fName, lName, pickUpDate FROM reservations_db WHERE pickUpDate = " + reportDate;
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        JasperReportBuilder report = DynamicReports.report();
        report
        .columns(
                Columns.column("Customer Id", "id", DataTypes.integerType()),
                Columns.column("First Name", "fName", DataTypes.stringType()),
                Columns.column("Last Name", "lName", DataTypes.stringType()),
                Columns.column("Date", "pickUpDate", DataTypes.stringType()))
        .title(Components.text("********Report By Date********")
                .setHorizontalTextAlignment(HorizontalTextAlignment.CENTER))
        .pageFooter(Components.pageXofY())
        .setDataSource(sql_statement, connection);

        try {
            report.show();
        } catch (DRException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter by datetime MYSQL formating](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657202/filter-by-datetime-mysql-formating)

Comment: Did you check the query with help of some MySQL client (MySQL Workbench, for example)? What is a type of *pickUpDate* column in DB?

Comment: @AlexK, the type of pickUpDate is String

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I got it working. The solution is very simple. I'm sharing the code here for future users. Instead of

```
sql_statement = "SELECT id, fName, lName, pickUpDate FROM reservations_db WHERE pickUpDate = " + reportDate;
```

write this:

```
sql_statement = "SELECT id, fName, lName, pickUpDate FROM reservations_db WHERE pickUpDate=$P{reportDate}"
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't promise that this will solve your particular problem, but it's worht giving a shot:
Instead of writing an entire query in your source, complete with "where" clauses and what not, make a function in SQL, which takes pickUpDate as a parameter, runs the query and returns table. And calling it will look something like this:
sql_statement = "select * from function_name(" + reportDate + ")"

I hope that helps, I work with jasperReports and my life's been a lot easier since I addopted this method. Cheers.

Comment: IMHO, it is a too expensive to create a function to make a simple filter

Comment: @D.Tabakov, can you please give me a sample sql function and how to call that function from java code? Do I write the sql function in mysql workbench, save it and call from java code?

Comment: @D. Tabakov, and are you talking about calling JasperReports api call or DynamicReport api call?

Comment: The function will look something like this

CREATE FUNCTION someName(IN report_date DATE)
RETURNS TABLE (id TEXT, fName TEXT, lName TEXT, pickUpDate DATE) AS
$BODY$
SELECT id, fName, lName, pickUpDate 
FROM reservations_db 
WHERE pickUpDate = report_date
$BODY$
LANGUAGE sql
</blink>
And then you call it (in SQL) like this:
<blink>
SELECT * FROM someName(CAST('21.12.2016' AS DATE))

and calling it in your Java code:

sql_statement = "SELECT * from someName(CAST(" + reportDate + " AS DATE)";

Comment: @D.Tabakov, thanks a lot. How can a user generate a report dynamically using this approach? It seems, you have to give the date manually  ("SELECT * FROM someName(CAST('21.12.2016' AS DATE)) ").

Comment: That depends on what you mean by dynamically. If the user has to choose a date for themselves, store their input in a variable and replace it in the query:
 sql_statement = "SELECT * from someName(CAST(" + userInput + " AS DATE))" To be honest, I can't be too speciffic, because I work with Postgres and JasperReports, and mainly program in PHP; But the basic idea is transferable - create and SQL function, which runs the query and returns the table, and call it in your report, replacing the parameters with the user input (or whatever else you may need)

Comment: @AlexK It is a bit expensive but it's also a very clean pattern to separate business logic from parameterization and presentation of the results. So I think worth the price.