# Get Birthday data date wise

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, sql-date-functions

I have a `dob(DATE)` field in table which stores birth dates of users. now i have query to get users who have birth date in this month is as follow

```
SELECT * FROM register WHERE MONTH(dob) = MONTH(NOW())
```

Which returns me users who have birthday on this month
now i wants to change search from month to `datewise` means if user are searching date wise so query returns me datewise date

e.g.

user search and variable in php i get as

```
$fromdate = 09-Mar-2018
$todate = 20-Mar-2018
```

Now my query should search  datewise instead of month wise.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16657202/filter-by-datetime-mysql-formatting

Comment: Send a filter from the front end and backend level use a logic to change the query based on filter, as an example, if you want to check date wise,

    $query = "SELECT * FROM register";
    if($filter == "dateWise"){
         $query." "."Where dob = NOW()";
    }else if($filter == "monthWise"){
         $query." "."Where MONTH(dob) = MONTH(NOW())";
    }

Use this type of thing to achieve your goal.

Comment: @AlivetoDie its not mark as duplicate as duplicate answer is in `%D%M%Y%h%i%s` Formate.

Comment: ok i have reopend it.wait for sometime and you will get answer.

Comment: @Sameera its good.! but i am finding one sql query to search by user selected date.

Comment: You can write query as: "SELECT * FROM register WHERE dob BETWEEN '$fromdate' AND '$todate' " OR query can be: "SELECT * FROM register WHERE dob >= '$fromdate' AND dob <= '$todate' "

Answer (score 0):

Send a filter from the front end and backend level use a logic to change the query based on filter, as an example, if you want to check date wise, `

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM register"; 
if($filter == "dateWise"){ 
$query." "."Where dob = NOW()";
 }else if($filter == "monthWise"){ 
$query." "."Where MONTH(dob) = MONTH(NOW())"; 
}`
```

Use this type of thing to achieve your goal.